# computing statistics after rebuilding indexes oracle

Tags: oracle

The execution time  of stored procedures were taking so much of time.so we were asked to rebuild indexes for the  entire schema and compute statistics.

Here my question is compute statistics has to be done on the table or index?

this is what i tried

```
ALTER INDEX SHIP_UNIT_PK REBUILD;  

exec dbms_stats.gather_index_stats('stage','SHIP_UNIT_PK ');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed .
```

What has to be done/or checked after this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing to do is, I think:

```
analyze table <yourtable> compute statistics;
```

But anyway if your table was not changed that much, it is enough to rebuild index.

Comment: `analyze table` is deprecated, don't use it any more. You should use the `dbms_stats` package.

Answer (score 0):

> [GATHER_TABLE_STATS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i1036461) Procedure
>
> This procedure gathers table and column (and index) statistics